# Flutter.dev and the problem with macOS Catalina (Gatekeeper)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, macos-catalina

since I upgraded my MacBook to macOS Catalina. I'm getting permanent the message ("ideviceinfo" could not be open, because the developer is not verified) despite I disabled the "spctl". can somebody help please?
I downloaded the flutter version flutter_macos_v1.9.1+hotfix.4-stable.zip AND i use the Andriod Studio 3.5.1.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.15 19A583, locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.4 at /Users/yousefmosa/0/prg/flutter
    • Framework revision cc949a8e8b (2 weeks ago), 2019-09-27 15:04:59 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/yousefmosa/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
        pod setup

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 40.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 37.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.7830

[✓] VS Code (version 1.37.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.3.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • XXX-6B2F-XXX-9B01-XXXXXX • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-0 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 10):

From macOS "System Preferences..." > "Security & Privacy" > "General" tab ,
you see the dart entry. Just press "Allow Anyway"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that and despite that. The System keep showing this message. I can not develop my app on macOS Catalina anymore :-(

Comment: most probably, you get errors from 'flutter doctor' command. Just follow the error message to get them all green. You might need to run 'flutter upgrade', cocoapods and something to make it all green.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System preferences -> General and allow "dart" to run

Answer (score 2):

Type these command in terminal

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine YourflutterSDKLocation/bin/cache/artifacts/libimobiledevice/ideviceinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of recent changes in macOS Catalina.

```
sudo spctl --add "Path_to_flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/libimobiledevice/ideviceinfo"
```

You might need to reboot the system in order to apply the changes.

You can run [a GateKeeper script](https://github.com/AmirKamali/Flutter_GateKeeper_Fix) to fix the issue.

I have [published an article](https://medium.com/@amir.n3t/how-to-fix-flutter-idevice-id-running-errors-in-mac-osx-catalina-7aa1f89f61aa) with more information how to fix this.